# Generate array of all combinations of an existing array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm

If I have an array in Ruby, like this:

```
["foo", "bar", "bat"]
```

How can I generate a new array with every combination of values?

I need the output to look like this:

```
["foo", "bar", "bat", "foo-bar", "foo-bat", "bar-bat", "foo-bar-bat"]
```

Order is unimportant. Also, I do not need *both* `"foo-bar"` and `"bar-foo"`.

The original array may have up to 5-6 members.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ar = ["foo", "bar", "bat"]
p 1.upto(ar.size).flat_map {|n| ar.combination(n).map{|el| el.join('-')}}
#=>["foo", "bar", "bat", "foo-bar", "foo-bat", "bar-bat", "foo-bar-bat"]
```

Comment: In ruby 1.9 you can use `flat_map` instead of `map` + `flatten`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try looking at the cross product of the two arrays

```
arr = %w(foo bar bat)

arr.product(arr).collect{|el| el.uniq.join("-")}
```

Comment: This does not give the desired result: `["foo", "foo-bar", "foo-bat", "bar-foo", "bar", "bar-bat", "bat-foo", "bat-bar", "bat"]`

Comment: This does not handle cases that combine more than 2 elements.

Comment: Ahh, you are correct. I misread your question. Not only did I only see pairs of elements, but I thought you _needed_ both orders. I will leave this here though in case it helps anyeone else.