# How to create all combinations for items in an Array?

Tags: java, kotlin

I did see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21258571/all-combinations-of-array) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900636/generate-array-of-all-combinations-of-an-existing-array) post on it, but it is not in Java or Kotlin, so it doesn't help me. Now, coming to the problem, I want to be able to create all the possible combinations for an array. For example, I have this array:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

And then all the possible combinations give us this:

```
[1,2,3,4]
[1,2,4,3]
[1,3,2,4]
[1,3,4,2]
[1,4,2,3]
[1,4,3,2]

[2,1,4,3]
[2,1,3,4]
[2,3,1,4]
[2,3,4,1]
[2,4,3,1]
[2,4,1,3]

[3,1,2,4]
[3,1,4,2]
[3,2,4,1]
[3,2,1,4]
[3,4,1,2]
[3,4,2,1]

[4,1,2,3]
[4,1,3,2]
[4,2,3,1]
[4,2,1,3]
[4,3,2,1]
[4,3,1,2]
```

*I don't want to have a space between these two different starts or numbers.  I just added it for readability.*

It should not only work for `Integers` but also for objects like strings, our classes, etc...

So, how can I achieve this in Java or Kotlin?

---

I also just came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72444687/print-all-possible-combinations-of-2-arrays-maintaining-order)* post, but it wanted for two arrays and needed for one. Also, it was closed, so I felt it better to ask another one.

- The post is now deleted

Comment: Quote: "Just let me know what can be better." What does that mean? There is no code in your post.

Comment: stackoverflow is not a code writing service. Post the code you have developed so far.

Comment: @lukas.j I don't actually need the entire code. Just a good logic would be good. And, I don't have any idea of what might be used. Why? Becuase I never know the size of the array. Just an example

Comment: The technical term for this is ‘[permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation)’. ‘[Combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination)’ are unordered subsets: for example, there are 6 combinations of 2 from {1, 2, 3, 4}: {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}.

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920315/permutation-of-array) you can find the answer of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the task is not to implement the algorithm which generates the permutations you need, I would recomend to use a library like [combinatoricslib3](https://github.com/dpaukov/combinatoricslib3). If you happen to use Guava or Apache Commons in your projects, those have also some methods to generate combinations / permutations from a given collection. With combinatoricslib3 your code could look something like:

```
import org.paukov.combinatorics3.Generator;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] array = {1,2,3,4};
        Generator.permutation(array)
                .simple()
                .stream()
                .forEach(System.out::println);

        //Example with strings

        Generator.permutation("apple", "orange", "cherry")
                .simple()
                .stream()
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 4, 3]
[1, 4, 2, 3]
[4, 1, 2, 3]
[4, 1, 3, 2]
....
```

and

```
[apple, orange, cherry]
[apple, cherry, orange]
[cherry, apple, orange]
[cherry, orange, apple]
[orange, cherry, apple]
[orange, apple, cherry]
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you expect to generate all possible permutations (N!), not combinations of given set of objects. Please check Guava's library
[Collections2.permutations](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html).

It takes collection of elements, and return Collection of Lists of those elements.

```java
public class Permutations {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> myList = List.of(1,2,3,4);
        // generate permutations of myList
        var permutations = Collections2.permutations(myList);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh. The docs. It is not easy to read such confusing docs(At least for me). It would be good if I could get an example of that.

Comment: I've added sample code, firstly u need to import Guava's lib 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava

Answer (score 0):

Without using a library:

```
fun List<Any>.permutations(): List<List<Any>> {
  if (isEmpty()) return listOf(emptyList())
  return indices.fold(emptyList()) { result, i ->
    (result + (this - this[i])
      .permutations()
      .fold(mutableListOf()) { acc, item ->
        acc.add(item + this[i])
        acc
      }
    ).toMutableList()
  }
}

listOf(1, 2, 3, 4).permutations().forEach(::println)

listOf("A", "B", "C", "D").permutations().forEach(::println)

data class Test (val name: String)
listOf(Test("A"), Test("B"), Test("C"), Test("D")).permutations().forEach(::println)
```